# Internal Death while parsing [stdin] cPanel

Tags: sqlite, cpanel

When I try to modify an account via cPanel WHM ,I got below error.

~~~

[2015-07-30 10:49:36 -0400] die [Internal Death while parsing [stdin] 11431] DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: database disk image is malformed at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Bandwidth.pm line 56.
Whostmgr::Bandwidth::catch {...} (Cpanel::Exception::Database::Error=HASH(0x72432a0)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/perl/514/lib64/perl5/cpanel_lib/Try/Tiny.pm line 104
Try::Tiny::try(CODE(0x7238338), Try::Tiny::Catch=REF(0x4918f48)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Whostmgr/Bandwidth.pm line 58
Whostmgr::Bandwidth::getmonthbwusage("username", "advicetr") called at whostmgr/bin/whostmgr.pl line 4366
main::edituser() called at whostmgr/bin/whostmgr.pl line 598

DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: database disk image is malformed
at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exception.pm line 151.
Cpanel::Exception::new("Cpanel::Exception::Database::Error", Cpanel::ExceptionMessage::Raw=SCALAR(0x49ea7e0), HASH(0x7242d48)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exception.pm line 57
Cpanel::Exception::create("Database::Error", Cpanel::ExceptionMessage::Raw=SCALAR(0x49ea7e0), HASH(0x7242d48)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/Exception.pm line 72
Cpanel::Exception::create_raw("Database::Error", "DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: database disk image is malformed", HASH(0x7242d48)) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DBI.pm line 105
Cpanel::DBI::_create_exception(Cpanel::DBI::SQLite::st=HASH(0x72387a0), "DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: database disk image is malformed", undef) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/DBI.pm line 93
Cpanel::DBI::_error_handler("DBD::SQLite::st execute failed: database disk image is malformed", Cpanel::DBI::SQLite::st=HASH(0x72387a0), undef) called at /usr/local/cpanel/Cpanel/BandwidthDB/RootCache.pm line 390

Can any know this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the error message involved bandwidth, I moved the /root/.bwusage.sqlite file out of the way and ran /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/build_bandwidthdb_root_cache_in_background

This generated a new .bwusage.sqlite file which should solve this issue.

Fixed !!!

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try to update your cPanel/WHM with the following command.

```
/scripts/upcp –force
```